# Rails: Why is my boolean field returning Fixnum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

We have a boolean field in our system (using Rails 3.0.4) and when attached to MySQL the fields report true and false as appropriate. When attached to Oracle (production) it is returning Fixnum. The column is of type NUMBER(1). Other models correctly return true and false. The controller is doing a simple find. This only happens on the show action. Index returns true false. This happens for both HTML and XML responses. When asking for the type of a field the Console reports a class of FalseClass or TrueClass. The View reports Fixnum.

What could possibly be going wrong?

***Updated: Code***

```
create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.boolean  "has_information"
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end
```

***Updated with a clearer question***

The Rails convention is to make the field a NUMBER(1) type column. Then converts it to a boolean in the model. This is working in several models in our application. Only ONE model is having this issue. And it only has the issue on the show action. The show action was created by scaffold so is very generic. Why would it Rails not follow convention in this one instance?

***Updated with solution***

It was fixed in this instance by calling Person.find_by_id!(params[:id]) instead of Person.find(params[:id]) Why the default was returning the wrong class for a field in a normal find is beyond me.

Comment: Show us your model code and schema.rb file

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I think Rails does not support Oracle by default? What is the adapter you are using?

Comment: The OracleAdapter. Oracle is definitely supported. Not well, but it is supported.

Comment: To be specific: activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter and ruby-oci8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, update the Oracle Adapter because it is out of date. Version 1.3.0 of the activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter gem has a bug that was reported:

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/7

We updated the driver and everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox sent back from the view is going to be a number, either "0" or "1" depending on if the checkbox is unchecked or checked respectively. You will need to convert this in your model to a `false` or `true` value if that is what your DB adapter requires it to be.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the form. That all works appropriately. The issue is with the show action. Rails for some reason decided that this field on this model is not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no BOOLEAN type in Oracle.  We usually use fields of CHAR(1), constrained to have values 'Y' and 'N'.  YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: The Rails convention is to make the field a NUMBER(1) type column. Then converts it to a boolean in the model. This is working in several models in our application. Only ONE model is having this issue. And it only has the issue on the show action. The show action was created by scaffold so is very generic. Why would it Rails not follow convention in this one instance?